# php prepared statements insert not working

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have researched it a lot online and spent a lot of time trying to fix this problem.
My code

```
    function createNewAccount() {

        global $response;
        global $conn;

        // prepare and bind
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);

        // set parameters and execute
        $firstname = "John";
        $lastname = "Doe";
        $email = "john@example.com";
        $stmt->execute();

}
```

the error I get is

> Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\authentication\register.php on line 105
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on
>   null in C:\xampp\htdocs\authentication\register.php:106 Stack trace:
>    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\authentication\register.php(139): createNewAccount() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\authentication\register.php on line 106

I cant seem to find any solution. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: PHP, those set parameters need to go before bind, then execute goes after bind

Comment: Avoid using `global` and pass any connections/resources around as parameters.

Comment: Show how you define `$conn`. And comment out any `conn->close()` you have in your code.

Comment: $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
tried commenting conn->close() as well. didnt work

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I have added error reporting as well. This error is strange.

Answer (score -2):

PHP Variables need to be set before using them:

```
function createNewAccount() {

    global $response;   // If you dont need this remove it
    global $conn;

   // set parameters and execute
    $firstname = "John";
    $lastname = "Doe";
    $email = "john@example.com";

    // prepare and bind
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);      
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

Comment: No they don't.  They are passed by reference and created and then changed.

Comment: Then your function is broken for another reason because that prepared statement is exactly as it should be. Don't downvote because you didn't supply enough information. Check your $conn because that's the only other thing it could be

Comment: thats the entire function. $conn is fine with other functions on the page. And i did not downvote anything here.